# Rmarkdown won't recognize latex line breaks in pdf

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

I am using rmarkdown to generate my homework which also involves including some equations in latex, but rmarkdown will not recognize line endings if I create a pdf file.

```
\[
Y = f(X) \\
X \in [0,1]
\]
```

If I specify the output as html, this will appear correctly as two lines, but when outputting to pdf, it will put the entire latex block on the same line. I have tried \newline and that still does not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do

```
\begin{align*}
Y = f(X) \\
X \in [0,1]
\end{align*}
```

This works for html and pdf.

Comment: This didn't work for me: 
\begin{align*}
S.a. \\
\sum_{i=1}^n w_ix_i = W \\
l_i \leq x_i \leq u_i \\
0 \leq l_i \leq 1 \\
l_i \leq u_i \leq 1 \\
\forall i = 1, \dots , n
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Maybe give the following a try:

```
\begin{aligned}
 Y = f(x) \\
 X \in [0,1]
\end{aligned}
```